# Gridview data not refreshing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview which has a List (Of MyObject) as its datasource.

```
gv.DataSource = MyListObject
gv.Databind()
```

Under a templatefield i have a button configured to delete a record from MyListObject and then rebind it. To add a record i have the below code

```
Protected Sub btnAddRecord_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddRecord.Click
    Dim Customer As New Customer

    With Customer
        .Name = txtName.Text
        .Surname = txtSurname.Text
        .....
        .ID += MyListObject.Count
    End With

    MyListObject.Add(Customer)

    gv.DataSource = MyListObject 
    gv.DataBind()
End Sub
```

This works fine, but then i need to allow the user to delete a record if need be:

```
Private Sub gv_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles gv.RowCommand
    If e.CommandName = "Delete" Then
        MyListObject.RemoveAt(e.CommandArgument)

        gv.DataSource = Nothing
        gv.DataBind()

        gv.DataSource = MyObjectList
        gv.DataBind()

        upnl.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional
        upnl.Update()
    End If
End Sub
```

When i click the button it deletes the record but doesnt refresh the data. By that i mean when the record is added i am assigning the ID as a row ID and then use that ID to remove the record. Since the List and Gridview values are now out of sync i set the datasource to nothing and rebind it in order that i was going to have the values reset and the ID would be the correct one - but this doesnt works as i expected.

Could anyone advise where im going wrong and how to correct this problem?

Comment: In your gv_RowCommand function, this line: 
gv.DataSource = _DirectorAddList
is actually referring to the MyListObject I'm guessing?
gv.DataSource = MyListObject

Comment: Remove the update panel and do normal page refresh to see if you get the desired results. That way you can pinpoint the proper reason.

Comment: Removing the update panels seems to point at my code, but im a little lost where the bug could be? MyListObject is a Shared private variable but if it isnt then it only remembers the last item added to the gridview?

Comment: Or if possible how could i get the RowIndex under the RowCommand event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' which resolved the issue as i was then deleting the row the user clicked against.

Answer (score 1):

Is `gridview` in the `updatepanel`? If yes, that panel should also be refreshed.

Comment: Also yes, what he's saying is right.  If you are able to run in Debug Mode and interrogate the gridview object after the databind on the updated datasource, if your gridview looks as you're expecting, quite possible you need to update an UpdatePanel that it lives within too.

Comment: I updated my code above to show what it looks like now. After adding the Update Panel code to the RowCommand event theres no difference. I will double check the values in debug mode unless anyone can see an obvious mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Just as a side note, I'd probably handle what get's updated when on the client side using the ajax script manager rather than doing it in the code behind.  Saves headaches.  The above might be updating the update panel correctly, but the ajax plumbing may not be there on the client side.